# Proof that ZF set theory implies Weak König's Lemma

Tags: set-theory

In some of my other questions and in several references one finds the statement that

> ZF axioms imply WKL

I have searched for the proof of this, but I so far cannot find a proof. I am looking for a proof not because I doubt it, but because I would like to know for sure which axioms are used in this proof.

I suspect that it may result from the underlying use of 2-valued logic (in ZF set theory) rather than any specific collection of ZF axioms, but I have not seen the proof to be sure.

Does anyone know where to find a proof that I can study?

Comment: Can you remind us old codgers losing our memory what the statement of Weak Konig is, so we dont have to look it up.

Comment: @Rene: Every countable $\omega$-tree has a branch.

Comment: @AsafKaragila 1) what is weak about this ? 2) This requires some choice as you point out in your answer.

Comment: @Rene: *countable*.

Comment: @AsafKaragila oh I see the whole tree is well ordered from the start...

Comment: @Rene: Hence weak. I suppose.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes well lets just add well ordered to the hypothesis of our theorems and work in ZF all the time...

Comment: @Rene: Yeah. Usually. This is an easy consequence of [choiceless absoluteness](http://arxiv.org/abs/1402.3048).

Comment: @AsafKaragila, Actually the formulation of WKL that I have from Reverse Mathematics texts is: for any infinite $T \subset 2^{<N}$ T will have an infinite branch. So this T will have terminal nodes in general. Is this equivalent to your formulation?

Comment: Roy, I don't know why you deleted the comment you posted on my answer and re-posted it here. But I already gave you an answer below my answer. You can read it there.

Answer (score 5):

This is a trivial observation.

> Suppose that $T=\{t_n\mid n\in\omega\}$ is a tree without any terminal nodes. Then $T$ has a branch.

*Proof.* Without loss of generality $t_0$ is the root of the tree. Now by induction let $f(0)=t_0$ and $f(n+1)=t_k$ if and only if $k=\min\{m\mid t_m\text{ is an immediate successor of }t_n\}$. Now $\{f(n)\mid n\in\omega\}$ is a branch. $\square$

In particular, a countable tree where every level is finite has an infinite branch.

And note that we didn't use any contradiction, or $2$-valued assumptions here. Since the well-ordering is given (and when it doesn't, we can instantiate the existential quantifier which assures that it does), we only have to "traverse" up the tree and pick the right node at each step.

So in order to not prove this, you'd have to be incapable of proving certain induction arguments.

---

This is not true that $\sf ZF$ proves this statement when $T$ is not countable from the beginning. An example of that is when consider a countable family of [non-empty] finite sets which does not admit a choice function $\{A_n\mid n\in\omega\}$, then the tree whose underlying set is $\bigcup_{n\in\omega}\prod_{k<n}A_k$ ordered by inclusion, is a counterexample.

Comment: Roy, there is a definable well-ordering of $2^{<\omega}$; so the answer is yes. As for the case of terminal nodes, you can remove all the finite branches; if the tree turned out to be empty then it was finite to begin with. As I keep saying, when the object you are working with is countable, the proofs which use the axiom of choice are almost always can be retraced by fixing an enumeration and using it for a choice function. Including this.

Comment: Thanks. So to return to the **ZF** Axiom aspect, is it the Axiom of Infinity which is giving us this mathematical induction result?

Comment: Well, if you replace the axiom of infinity with its negation, you get a theory which is bi-interpretable with $\sf PA$, so clearly the axiom of infinity causes a lot of this mess.

Comment: OK, just for definiteness, does that remark mean that **WKL** cannot be derived (proof theoretically) from **ZF + -I** (at least via your Induction proof)?

Comment: What's $2^{<\omega}$ in a theory which cannot talk about infinite sets? Note that $\sf WKL$ is in its nature a second-order statement.

Comment: So **WKL** cannot even be *stated* in **ZF-I**? If it cannot be stated then it certainly cannot be proven?

Comment: You can try and circumvent this by using a schema (since the tree is essentially definable), but then you will lose the fact that the tree is a subtree of the real binary tree, and I think you can prove all the instances of the schema anyway (although I am not sure).